# React Native access the image from the API call

Tags: reactjs, react-native

How do I access the image in the current json structure from my react native app-

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "height": "160",
    "student": {
      "name": "John",
      "studentImages": [
        {
          "thumbnail": true,
          "path": "https://..."
        },
        {
          "thumbnail": false,
          "path": "https://..."
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

What I have currently is -

```
return this.state.studentDataList.map((studentData) => {
            return (
                <View>
                    <Card image={require('img')}>
                        <Text>{studentData.student.name}</Text>
                    </Card>
                </View>
            )
        })
```

For the Card image I need to access the `student.studentImages.path` and take the image which has thumbnail as true. How do I access it?

Comment: What is the `Card` component?

Comment: It is the card view from react-native-elements

Comment: try `<Card image={{ uri: studentData.student.studentImages[0].path}}>` and see any images is appearing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to filter out from the thumbnail image array to give you the first thumbnail which is true.

```
return this.state.studentDataList.map((studentData) => {
                let thumbnailData = studentData.student.studentImages;
                let image = thumbnailData.find((img) => img.thumbnail);
                let imageSrc = image.path || '';
                return (
                    <View>
                        <Card image={imageSrc}>
                            <Text>{studentData.student.name}</Text>
                        </Card>
                    </View>
                )
            })
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code which return `Card` component if the thumbnail is true

```
return this.state.studentDataList.map(studentData => {
            studentData.student.studentImages.map(studentImages=>{
                return (
                    {studentImages.thumbnail && 
                    <View>
                        <Card image={{ uri:studentImages.path }}>
                            <Text>{studentData.student.name}</Text>
                        </Card>
                    </View>}
                );
            })
        })
```